# red-black tree - construction

Tags: creation, red-black-tree

Recently, I have been going through search trees and I encountered red-black trees, the point confusing me is, In r-b tree, the root node should be black thats fine, now how will I decide whether the incoming node assumes red or black color.

I have gone through the wiki article but have not found a solution for this. I might be wrong, but I would be happy if someone can guide me through the exact material.

[Edit]
That is for example, if my keys are {7, 2, 4, 1, 9, 10, 8}

Here 7 is root and it assumes black color, but what color does 2 assume? How do we decide that? And how do we decide what color the other nodes assume?

```
                                  7 - (Black)
                   2                              9
           1                   4        8                    10
        NIL   NIL          NIL  NIL   NIL  NIL            NIL  NIL
```

Do we have a random toss that decides the color of the node to be red or black. Or is it some other process.

Thank you.

Comment: The thing is, you never paint your entire tree in one shot. You always insert your nodes one by one and correct the rest of your tree

Comment: The incoming new node always colored RED first, then you do the check on the tree properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the lecture about red-black trees on MIT open courseware.

http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/VideoLectures/

I found them to be very helpful.

Now if I remember correctly, you always insert new node as black node and then proceed to the necessary corrections (repainting and/or rotations)

Comment: Yes I have seen the video but I don't find an answer in it. Thank you for that as it made me understand other concepts clearly.

Comment: Actually you insert each new node as a RED (not black) node and then proceed with the corrections. The reason is to keep the following property true: "For each node, all paths from the node to descendant leaves contain the same number of black nodes.". If you insert the new node as a black one you increase the number of black nodes on one of the paths.

Answer (score 1):

The incoming node must be colored RED because if you color an incoming node to be black than height of all leaf to root path for newly inserted node is going to increase by one which is going to violate RB tree property that every root to leaf path must contain equal number of black nodes.Refer this if you want more insight in insertion of RB tree http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QOKk_pcv3U